# Trying to scale Azure SQL DB using MSI for identity not autharised to perform action

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

I am creating my first app function using powershell in the Azure portal, It's just to scale a SQLDB on  I have tried to use this tutorial as a guide.
[MSI example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBi1bll2928&list=WL&index=3&t=728s)

I turned on MSI for the function and configured resources groups Giving the contributor role to the resource

When I run the function within the portal, I get the message doesn't have authorization to perform action.  from this tutorial I believe this is all I had to do ?  I have waited over a day to see if it's a timing issue, from the example I Have followed and this MS document [managed identies for app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet)

I don't believe I need to add any secret key for this to work?

[Function Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOBir.png)

[Setting the function MSI identity to on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uala5.png)

[Seeting the access control in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EufEp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The service principal you are using doesn't have rights within that tenant.**

Tenants have subscriptions and service principals belong to tenants. Azure resource manager also exposes role based authorization for a given principal, which would give it rights on Azure resources. It appears the service principal doesn't have rights to read from that subscription.

Go to portal and find your `subscription`, click on `Access Control (IAM)` and then click on `Add role assignment` with `correspond service principal` which you use to acquire token.

After you have given successful permission, refresh and try again.

Comment: *Go to portal and find your subscription, click on Access Control (IAM) and then click on Add role assignment with correspond service principal which you use to acquire token*  That is what I did *configured resources groups Giving the contributor role to the resource*  Sorry I may not have made that very clear.

Comment: Add your MSI service principal into subscription with contributor role.